# $routeProvider not passing search parameter route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, route-provider

I'm trying to create a toggle that switches between two tables on one page. I have both the tables defined in my index.html within a `<body ng-app="main">` tag as

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table1.html">
    some code
 </script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table2.html">
   some code
</script>
```

My `$routeProvider` is then defined in my .js as

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider.when('/?table=table1', {
      controller:'PostsCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'table1.html'
   })
   $routeProvider.when('/?table=table2', {
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'table2.html' 
   })

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/?table=table1'});
}]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

ngRoute as been added as a dependency, the controller has been defined and the search parameter was added to the URL by an href surrounding each button in a btn-group.
I am supposed to be able to click either button and it will switch to the table but right now all that happens when I click the buttons are the page refreshing and the search parameter updating accordingly.
Anyone know why `$routeProvider` doesn't seem to be routing to my .html?

Comment: I don't think routes work with query strings

Comment: maybe bcoz its searching for `table1.html` and `table2.html` files

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by including `<div ng-view></div>` immediately before the close tag related to the `ng-app` tag.